# Flash As3 Window resize issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a flash script, i added one move clip via addChild, my movie area is 500x400
and the movieClip i aligned to center. But when am trying to set the size with in browser its not aligned to center. all my calculations are getting wrong.

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import fl.motion.Color;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.Security;

    public class main extends Sprite {

        public function main(){
            trace("Hello");


            var btn:_Button = new _Button();
            btn.x= (stage.stageWidth - btn.width)/2
            btn.y= (stage.stageHeight - btn.height)/2
            addChild(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code

Answer (score 3):

You need at add listeners to resizeEvent and FullScreen Events.

```
public function main():void {
  stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
  stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
  ...
  ...
  stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
  stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, resizeHandler);
  ...
}
```

private function resizeHandler(e:Event):void {
  btn.x= (stage.stageWidth - btn.width)/2
  btn.y= (stage.stageHeight - btn.height)/2
}

Answer (score 0):

if center aligned

```
btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
```

if top left

```
btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - btn.width / 2;
btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - btn.height / 2;
```

Comment: WHAT IS THIS? I DON'T UNDERSTAND.
I NEED TO CHECK MY SCALEING FACTOR, MY EQUATIONS ARE CORRECT. BUT THE  FLASH SETTINGS ...